# Debian doesn't run cron after moving boot disk

Tags: ssh, boot, cron, sd-card

I'm working on a bunch of custom scripts for Debian to run on an Odroid. My OS is on an SD card.

Recently I needed to clone this SD card to another Odroid. I copied an image using Win32DiskImager on my Windows PC and wrote that image to a fresh SD card. After booting from this SD card on the second Odroid I found that a lot of things had mysteriously broken.

Firstly my /etc/network/interfaces file got wiped, so I had to manually reenter info for the eth0 and lo. More frustrating than this though is that for some reason, at least two services don't run on boot anymore, namely SSH and cron. This is really troublesome.

I'm not sure how to rectify this or how to stop it from happening again. This is a big problem for me since I need to copy this image to a lot of Odroids.

Comment: I would advise trying to including a modicum of technical detail and debugging here. Otherwise, you are just asking people to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Network configuration is tied to a specific interface - if you've put image in second piece of hardware without telling it, the MAC will have changed and it won't apply your network settings to the new NIC.  Lookup `udev`, and the contents of `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

I suspect SSH isn't starting because it depends on network, which has failed because there is no functional NIC.  Fix this, and other stuff will start working as a consequence.  Maybe that will fix everything, but if there are still issues we will need more detail to help further - recent log content, or output of what happens when you manually start cron, for example.